# MERGE into first table based on id of second table if not matched

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have two tables table_1 and table_2. After inserting some data into table_1(insert not in the example below), it gives Auto_Increment ID to table_1. Then I need to put this new generated ID into table_2 in NOT MATCHED section. 
I am trying to use T-SQL's `MERGE`, to `UPDATE` table if data already exists (if matched) or `INSERT INTO` table if there is no such data(not matched), but in second case insert by using one column selected from another table. 
Here is what I have already tried:

```
MERGE
INTO table_2 WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
USING (SELECT
        '42' AS person_id
        ,2 AS skill_id
) AS source
(person_id,skill_id )
ON (target.person_id = source.person_id
AND target.skill_id = source.skill_id)
    WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE
    SET  skill_lvl=4,already_have=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED
--section below doesn't work,because insert inside MERGE has to be without select (?)
THEN INSERT (person_id,  skill_id, skill_lvl,already_have)
    SELECT 42, id,3,1 FROM table_1;
```

Not matched section gives me an error that he waits values or default, but it seems kind of tricky to select with `values` or `default`.

**Edit_1** 
Insert query to table_1 (happens before previous MERGE. Both MERGES within one loop):

```
MERGE
INTO table_1 WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
USING (SELECT
        'skill_1' AS skill_name
) AS source
(skill_name)
ON (target.skill_name = source.skill_name)
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (category_id,skill_name)  values (0,'skill_1');
```

this query in the loop, compares skill_names, if name is not inside this table_1, it inserts this value. Then compare next skill_name and so on. ID's are generating automatically after inserting.

Comment: Extend `source` to select from `table_1` and/or use a variable to hold the captured `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Your current approach is flawed even if that syntax was accepted, since it seems to assume `table_1` only ever has a single row; you'd expect a `WHERE`.

Comment: Why are you using `MERGE` for this? What is the real `source` (not a hard-coded pair of values)? (Please read [these thoughts on `MERGE`](https://michaeljswart.com/2021/08/what-to-avoid-if-you-want-to-use-merge/)).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, it is the real `source` - it is the data that comes from another place (frontend), and it comes several times with several data, my `merge` query is inside loop based on amount of `sources`. Probably my approach is bad, if there is another solution would be great to see)

Comment: You'll need to show the insert into table_1 and how you've determined which values from the front end need a new ID from table_1. I can figure out the update based on your existing code, but I can't make sense of the insert you're trying to write either.

Comment: I found solution by not using `merge` - first comparing ids between tables ( I was using table_1 left join table_2 by skill_id's) and creating `if-else` statement (if null -insert, else update).  In `update` I have where id=skill_id - this skill_id I took from frontend. But for my question will try to use @JeroenMostert approach by extending source.

Comment: Code:
`declare @var1 int;
select @var1=a.id
from table_1 a
left join table_2 b on(a.id=b.skill_id)
if @var1 IS NULL
INSERT INTO table_2(person_id,  skill_id, skill_lvl,already_have)
  values (42,@var1,3,1)
else UPDATE table_2 SET  skill_lvl=1,already_have=1 
where skill_id = 6
and person_id=42;`